# What value does $\frac{n\ln{(x+1)}}{(n+1)\ln{x}}$ approach as $x\to\infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> What value does $\frac{n\ln{(x+1)}}{(n+1)\ln{x}}$ approach as $x\to\infty$?

We know $\frac{n}{n+1}\to 1$, but how about $\frac{\ln{(x+1)}}{\ln{x}}$?

Could someone suggest a solution?

Comment: Remember that $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is independent of $x$, so it's a constant.

Comment: Hint: Use l'Hopital's rule on the logarithms

Comment: At inifinity $x$ and $x+1$ do not differ, then $n/(n+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

One may notice that, by the Taylor expansion, as $u \to 0$,
$$
\ln (1+u)=u+O(u^2)
$$ giving, as $ x \to \infty$,
$$
\ln (1+x)=\ln x+\ln \left(1+\frac1x \right)=\ln x+\frac1x +O\left( \frac1{x^2}\right)
$$ or, as $ x \to \infty$,

> $$
> \frac{\ln (1+x)}{\ln x}=1+\frac1{x\ln x} +O\left( \frac1{x^2\ln x}\right).
> $$

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use L'hopital's rule, then write $\dfrac{\ln(x+1)}{\ln x} = \dfrac{\ln\left(x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)}{\ln x}= \dfrac{\ln x + \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\ln x}= 1 + \dfrac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\ln x}\to 1$, as $x \to \infty$. Thus $\dfrac{n\ln(x+1)}{(n+1)\ln x} \to \dfrac{n}{n+1}$